# Gazebo Irobot model "explodes"

Tags: ros, gazebo, irobot-create, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS, having just installed the software yesterday. Today I started working with Gazebo to try and run some simulations. The specific platform I am trying to simulate is the iRobot create. I used rosinstall to add the required packages from aptima-ros-pkg and ua-ros-pkg as outlined [here](https://wiki.nps.edu/display/%7Ethchung/ROS+--+iRobot+Create). I created the urdf file by performing

`` `rospack find xacro`/xacro.py `rospack find irobot_create_description`/urdf/create.urdf.xacro > ~/ros_workspace/robot.urdf ``

I then proceeded to try to insert the model an empty world using roslaunch and rosrun, but [chaos ensued](http://youtu.be/TRJx99501Qc) (apologies for the poor video quality).

The output from the terminal I was running Gazebo in is

`` [ INFO] [1338498008.681508282, 266.797000000]: starting diffdrive plugin in ns: //
Warning [Param.cc:314] Parameter [xyzOffsets] is not a vector3, try parsing
Warning [Param.cc:314] Parameter [rpyOffsets] is not a vector3, try parsing
Dbg plugin model name: robot1
[ INFO] [1338498008.696764900, 266.797000000]: starting gazebo_ros_controller_manager plugin in ns: /
[ INFO] [1338498008.702468002, 266.797000000]: Callback thread id=0xaeb61550
gzclient: /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-visualization-common-1.8.4/debian/ros-fuerte-visualization-common/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/OgreMain/src/OgreNode.cpp:413: virtual void Ogre::Node::setPosition(const Ogre::Vector3&): Assertion `!pos.isNaN() && "Invalid vector supplied as parameter"' failed.
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui: line 2:  4751 Aborted                 `rospack find gazebo`/gazebo/bin/gzclient -g `rospack find gazebo`/lib/libgazebo_ros_paths_plugin.so
[gazebo_gui-2] process has died [pid 4748, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/dkleszyk/.ros/log/8123d130-ab61-11e1-a507-00216a4e4e76/gazebo_gui-2.log].
log file: /home/dkleszyk/.ros/log/8123d130-ab61-11e1-a507-00216a4e4e76/gazebo_gui-2*.log ``

I saw an [earlier Q&A](http://answers.ros.org/question/31654/gazebo-robot-oscillates-after-spawn/) that suggested commenting out `cannonicalBody` in the urdf file, but this did not solve the issue.

I am running ROS fuerte on Ubuntu 11.10. Any suggestions as to why the model would act like this?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35393/gazebo-irobot-model-%22explodes%22/) by [dkleszyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/2510/dkleszyk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-05-31

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) on 2012-06-29**:
A similar explosion occurs for me, when running the erratic teleop in wg_collada.world . The difference is that gazebo explodes only when I run the robot into the wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We encountered the same problem, i.e. Gazebo exploding just right after initializing with the reported error

```
gzserver: /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-visualization-common-1.8.4/debian/ros-fuerte-visualization-common/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/OgreMain/src/OgreNode.cpp:413: virtual void Ogre::Node::setPosition(const Ogre::Vector3&): Assertion `!pos.isNaN() && "Invalid vector supplied as parameter"' failed.
```

The crash appeared when including the stereo camera in the URDF of the REEM humanoid (https://github.com/pal-robotics) in Fuerte. The solution in our case was to increase the **inertia matrix** of the link in which the camera is mounted on.

---

Originally posted by [Jordi Pages](https://answers.ros.org/users/626/jordi-pages/) with karma: 245 on 2012-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0